# Intercepting & using the value of an optional variable captured in the dots (...)

Tags: r, parsing

I need to intercept the value of an optional `xlim` in a function so that I can change the units of it before plotting.  The following function confirms that `xlim` was passed, but I can't access the value.

```
foo <- function(x, y, ...) {
    if ("xlim" %in% names(list(...))) {
        print(xlim) # not found/can't use value!
        }
    # modify xlim and pass to plotting functions
    return()
    }
```

But `foo(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, xlim = c(2,4))` gives:

```
Error in print(xlim) : object 'xlim' not found
```

What trick do I need use the value?  Seems like it should just work, but I see from looking around on SO that the dots can be vexing.  I've played a bit with `exists`, `deparse` etc but I don't really 'get' the proper use of those functions.

EDIT: so here is the final snippet which was the leanest way to access the value:

```
dots <- list(...)
if (any(names(dots) == "xlim")) {
    xlim <- dots$xlim
    print(xlim)
    }
```

Comment: Be careful with `grepl`. It returns a vector, which in turn may give incorrect results in  `if`.  Try it with two dots arguments and see the difference.  It should give a warning

Comment: Ah, yes.  Repaired.  Thanks for your keen eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `xlim` is actually a list element, and is not (yet) an actual object in the function's environment.  You could do

```
foo <- function(x, y, ...) {
    m <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
    if(any(names(m) == "xlim")) m[["xlim"]]
    else stop("no xlim value")
}
foo(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, xlim = c(2,4))
# c(2, 4)
foo(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, ylim = c(2,4))
# Error in foo(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, ylim = c(2, 4)) : no xlim value
```

You can see what `match.call` is doing if we examine the function as

```
f <- function(x, y, ...) {
    match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
}
```

It is a list of all the entered dot arguments with their respective expressions, so there are many different ways to get the values, the above is just one way.

```
f(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, xlim = c(2,4))
# $xlim
# c(2, 4)
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
g <- function(x, y, ...) {
    dots <- list(...)
    any(names(dots) == "xlim")
}
g(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, xlim = c(2,4))
# [1] TRUE
```

Also keep in mind that `match.call` keeps the argument as an unevaluated `call`, while `list(...)` evaluates the argument.  This might be important for you passing the argument to other functions.

Comment: Thank you!  I just added `Xlim <- m[["xlim]]` so I could use the value elsewhere.  And thanks for the additional examples/explanation.

Comment: "not (yet) an actual object in the function's environment" Thanks: that at least explains why I couldn't get various permutations of `exist` to work.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `match.call` keeps the argument as an unevaluated call, while `list(...)` evaluates the argument